# how to set zoom level in 25km in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

I would like set my google map zoom level 25km. How it will be set my google api map please help me

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html) first.

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
```

The second parameter should be the zoom level.

Comment: Also to note, zoom level cannot be set in km.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's not such weird question, assuming he read the documentation, and knows he can set the zoomlevel in a ratio. This ratio is a kind of weird choice... it depends on the initial chosen bounds, and not very intuitive in that matter.

Here lies maybe the answer, you could define 2 points around the point you want to show, one northwest of the point (distance 12,5 km.) and 1 point southwest (also 12,5 km disctance). Than create bounds with this points and zoom to this bound.

A lot of coding, but it can be done.

So you should consider whether you want this, or just choose a proper inital zoomlevel.... (in ratio, not in km)